# Simplifying return of If Statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring, simplify

I'm having writers block on this if statement and simplifying it. Is there a more efficient way to implement this if the nests are returning the same value?  I may just be missing it.

```
            if (string == "something")
            {
                if (object1 == null || object2 == null || object3 == null)
                {
                    return state1;
                }
            }

            if (attribute1 || attribute2 || attribute3)
            {
                return state1;
            }

            return state 2;
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want this code to do?

Comment: Nesting can be combined with `&&` and the second block with `||`.

Comment: Just combine all your `||` conditions in one line `if(string == "something" && (object1 == null || object2 == null || object3 == null) || attribute1 || attribute2 || attribute3)`

Comment: Just combine the conditions.  `if (string == "something") &&(object1 == null || object2 == null || object3 == null) || (attribute 1 || attribute2` ... etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem. Also, that's not valid c#, maybe a type-o: `return state 2;`

Comment: I know lot of people are not fan of nesting but having a too long "if" condition make it harder to read than a nested if.

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, you could combine your conditions:

```
        if (string == "something" 
            && (object1 == null || object2 == null || object3 == null))
        {
            return state1;
        }

        if (attribute1 || attribute2 || attribute3)
        {
            return state1;
        }

        return state 2;
```

But I'd take the time to ask why you've got `object1`, `object2`, `object3`, etc.

Is the number of objects likely to change? If so, will they change together, or separately from one another? Is there something similar about these objects and attributes which ties them together? If so, you may end up with something like this:

```
        var objects = new[]{object1,object2,object3}; // a list of your objects
        if (string == "something" && objects.Any(o => o == null))
        {
            return state1;
        }

        var attributes=new[]{attribute1,attribute2,attribute3};
        if (attributes.Any(a => a))
        {
            return state1;
        }

        return state 2;
```

Or this:

```
        var things = ...; // each thing has an object and an attribute?
        if (string == "something" && things.Any(t => t.Object == null))
        {
            return state1;
        }

        if (things.Any(a => a.Attribute))
        {
            return state1;
        }

        return state 2;
```

On the other hand, if these objects and attributes are totally unrelated to each other, but there's something special about the combined conditions, you may want to use a variable name to at least indicate your intent.

```
        var objectsAreRequired = string == "something";
        var objectIsMissing = object1 == null || object2 == null || object3 == null;
        if (objectsAreRequired && objectIsMissing)
        {
            return state1;
        }
        ...
```

You could also combine these techniques, and that gets things to the point where a ternary operator might be more readable.

```
var objectsAreRequired = string == "something";
var objectIsMissing = things.Any(t => t.Object == null);
var isBlocked = things.Any(t => t.Attribute);
var errorExists = objectsAreRequired && objectIsMissing || isBlocked;
return errorExists ? state1 : state2;
```

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't really shock me but if you want to get rid of the nested `if` you can do this :

```
        if (string == "something" && (object1 == null || object2 == null || object3 == null) || attribute1 || attribute2 || attribute3)
        {
            return state1;
        }
```

But having too much conditions can make it more complex to read than a nested `if` in my opinion. Alternative would be something like that :

```
var meaningfulVariable1 = string == "something"           
var meaningfulVariable2 = (object1 == null || object2 == null || object3 == null)
var meaningfulVariable3 = (attribute1 || attribute2 || attribute3)

return ((meaningfulVariable1 && meaningfulVariable2) || meaningfulVariable3) ? "state1" : "state2"
```

If the `ternary` operator become too complex you can also merge more variable maybe "meaningfulVariable1" and "meaningfulVariable2" once put together represent something else ?

The important thing is your code can be easily read by someone else. That's why you should have meaningful variable name. Of course your code here is pretty generic so I can guess the correct name of it :-)